# Appending and prepending <s> tags (strike-through) to table data when checking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to use jQuery to convert everything in class "tableEntry" to strikethrough text (using "s" tags)  when my checkbox is clicked.  I'm currently having trouble appending and prepending  tags to the text  shown in the "tableEntry" class. How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<tr> 
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td><span class="tableEntry">Walk the Dog</span></td>
</tr>
```

jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("change", "input:checkbox", function () {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with CSS.

You can toggle a class on the element and use `text-decoration: line-through` to achive this.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w55t1en/)

```
$(document).on("change", "input:checkbox", function () {
  $(this).parent().next().find('span').toggleClass('strike');
});
```

```
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

---

But if you have to wrap/unwrap the element with an `<s>` tag (as your question implies), then you could use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/o77089hq/)

```
$(document).on("change", "input:checkbox", function () {
  var $span = $(this).parent().next().find('span');

  this.checked ? $span.wrap('<s></s>') : $span.unwrap();
});
```